# i want to save multi input value on different value using react js

Tags: html, reactjs, setstate

i have shop section show product
i want to save quantity of different input on different values how to do it and i want when he click button return with quantity value on input!!

```
   {
            Object.keys(product).map(arr => 
     <div className='Card'> 
     <div className='iconCard' >  <img  src={Icon} className="icon-card" alt="cardicon"  />
     </div>
     <div>
     <h2> {product[arr].title}</h2>
     </div>
     <div>
     <input type='number' key={1} id='input-value' ref={textInput}  min={1} max={100}  className='NumberSelect' placeholder={t('Quantity')}/>

     </div>
     <div>
      <h3 style={InputSearch}>  {product[arr].price} 150{t('price')} </h3>
      </div>
      <div className='Card-Button'>
      <button onClick={()=> onOnclickHandler()}> {t('Buy')}   </button>
      </div>
     </div>
}
```

how to save multi input value using react or how just to retrun the input value when the user click button ?

Comment: Just to make sure whether I understand it correctly, you need to input values for multiple product cards. So that number will be the quantity of each product. Once the user click the button, you need to return those quantity values using a function. Is this what you want to do ? Please provide the complete code file as well.

Comment: yes but i want when he click button buy  to select the quanitty input just one input only and how to divide them each quantity .

i think to use usestate but it wouldn't solve the issue bease it handle one input not multi inputs?

Comment: No, you can use a state to keep an object to handle these quantities. For each product, have an `id`. Then save the quantity relevant to that `id` inside the state object. So it will basically look like this `{id: quantity}`. As an example `{1: 25, 2: 45, 3: 89}`

Comment: okay greate idea can you just help me how to code it 
and the product i get from the api using map!

Comment: and how to make quantity increase based on the product id ?

Comment: Can you please provide your complete code using a code sandbox ? Using above code snippet, not possible to provide a proper solution.

Comment: i edit the question with my code using map! 
and the api retrun (product_typ, typ_name, prodcut_value , company_name)